# Intel Graphics Update tool for Linux - Failing at signing the packages after download (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, ppa, intel-graphics, intel

When I run the graphics update tool it all works fine, until I reach the final stage, which looks like the following:

```
Ensuring consistent system... OK
Listing packages... OK
Setting up repositories... OK
Installing packages...
Updating package cache... Failed
```

And the error output is:

```
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
W:https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key 09D6EF97BFB38E916EF060E756A3DEF863961D39 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1), 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have followed the recommandations on https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2 and did as explained under Ubuntu.

I even did `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

And it gives the following error

```
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Hit:14 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key 09D6EF97BFB38E916EF060E756A3DEF863961D39 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

How can I work around this issue so that I can use the Intel software to update graphic drives on my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

This repo is using a deprecated digest algorithm , SHA1 has been found to too collision prone for this purpose.

You need to contact the repoistory's maintainer and ask them to regenerate the release file with a better digest algorithm.

Comment: How? Where is this going to be?

Comment: there is more info here https://01.org/linuxgraphics

Comment: I managed to ask them a questions here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forum/graphics-installer-discussions/new-ubuntu-16.04-packages-use-unknown-key-again?page=2#comment-2762 Hopefully they will respond with a fix.